Is there an overview of all Spring Framework 6 modules?
For Spring Framework 4 there is this nice overview of all modules (see "2.2 Modules"):
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html
However, this overview seems to be largely outdated. The WebFlux module is not listed and some modules, such as the Portlet module, no longer seem to exist in Spring Framework 6, according to the GitHub page:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework
Is there such an overview for all Spring Framework 6 modules?

No there isn't anymore. All modules are listed in the github repo and the image that ones was (which was not complete either) is no more.
